# KDevelop 5 Beta, installed from PPA, ugly looking icons

Tags: icons, ppa, kdevelop, oxygen

I have installed KDevelop 5 from [ppa:blaze/kf5](https://launchpad.net/~blaze/+archive/ubuntu/kf5) . It worked well and saved me from the dirty compilation process. But unfortunately, KDevelop looks very ugly, it lacks some icons. It uses Ubuntu GTK icons, instead of Breeze or Oxygen. Even though I have installed packages related to those icons, nothing changed. How can I configure my system to make KDevelop use Breeze or Oxygen icons?

Note: Using Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Install (and use) `qt5ct`, and set your platform theme to that (`export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct`). Some environments do not set a platform theme at all, and then you get very bad-looking results. Hopefully these times will soon be over.

Comment: I started KDevelop with the option above, but first, all texts are extra large, and second, there are no icons at all. I also have the problem with ugly kdevelop icons. Using Kubuntu 23.04. How come, it is 2023 and still KDevelop uses these ugly icons by default. For other KDE applications, icons are fine.